# Server UPS problem

Tags: ups

My sever needs 10Kva UPS but i have connected all the six rack severs+ SAN storage in a 5 Kva UPS...power shut down is 99.9% impossible..but still wat would happen if power goes off ! suggest and advice..!

Comment: If your UPS are under powered you may trip the circuit breaker or you may damage equipment.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you need 10Kva, and only have 5Kva UPS, you're servers are going to go down ... hard. The only real solution is to get a properly sized UPS.